# Compact embedding of the Sobolev space $H^m(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\Omega)$ from Rellich-Kondrachov theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compactness, embeddings

From the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem we know that $H^m(\Omega)\hookrightarrow_c L^2(\Omega)$ when $\Omega$ is bounded of class $C^1$ and $m\geq 1$ is an integer. Also this is not true if $\Omega:=\mathbb{R}$. See for example Chapter 9 of *Bresis - Functional analysis, Sobolev spaces and partial differential equations, 2010,* or Chapter 6 of *Adams, Fournier - Sobolev spaces, 2003* for details.

**My question is** do we have the same compact embedding in the cases:

1. $H^m(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$,
2. $H^m(\Omega_1)$ and $L^2(\Omega_2)$, where $\Omega_1 \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$?

The reason I am asking is that I work on a problem where I would like to use the Aubin-Lions theorem to show some compact embedding. Reminder of the Aubin-Lions theorem: Let $X_1 \hookrightarrow_c X_2 \hookrightarrow X_3$ be three Banach spaces, where $X_1$ and $X_3$ are reflexive and as usual $\hookrightarrow$ and $\hookrightarrow_c$ stand for the continuoous and compact embeddings.. Let $a \in (0,1)$. Then
$$L^2(0,T;X_1)\cap W^{a,2}(0,T;X_3) \hookrightarrow_c
L^2(0,T;X_2).$$

**Additional questions:**

$\bullet$ I was wondering could $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be given on a three different spaces e.g. $X_1(\Omega_1), X_2(\Omega_2), X_3(\mathbb{R})$  where $\Omega_1 \subset \mathbb{R}$, $\Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\Omega_1 \subset \Omega_2$? Or more precisely in the case I am interested in could I use $X_1:=H^m(\Omega_1)$, $X_2:=L^2(\Omega_2)$ (this is why I am interested in the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem) and $X_3:=H^{-m}(\mathbb{R})$? I noticed that in the Aubin-Lions theorem it is nowhere said that the spaces $X_1, X_2, X_3$ need to be on the same set (whether it is $\Omega$ or $\mathbb{R}$).

$\bullet$ And also I am not sure could we have compact embeddings on $\mathbb{R}$ or it always it needs to be on some subset of $\mathbb{R}$?

I usually avoid dealing with compact embedding theorems so I don't know much about them and I hope that I didn't asked the obvious. Help with this would be great and I definitely need it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get compactness by composing the the (compact) embedding of $H^m(\Omega_1)$ into $L^2(\Omega_1)$ with the isometric embedding of the latter into $L^2(\Omega_2)$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, thank you for the comment. That should answer the case 2. of the first question.  Is the same working for the case 1. of the first question, i.e. do I have a compact embedding when the sets are $H^m(\Omega)$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R})$? I am never sure about compact embeddings when I have $\mathbb{R}$ involved.

Comment: Yes, the same. Boundedness Is used only for $\Omega_1$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, Thank you for the follow up. Concerning two additional questions: That means (I think) that I can use the Aubin-Lions theorem if $X_1 (\Omega_1)$ and the rest could be even $X_2(\mathbb{R})$, $X_3 (\mathbb{R})$. Also (I think) then I could have compact embeddings such as $X \hookrightarrow_c Y$ as long as $X$ is defined on some bounded set. (I hope that my conclusions are not wrong)

Comment: Well I do not know the setting precisely, but  if you compose bounded linear emebdeddings (or operators) and one is compact, then the whole is compact. I used only that; if this is the case in your setting, there is no problem.

Comment: The question is intriguing, but there is no unique way to define the injection $X_1(\Omega_1)\hookrightarrow X_2(\Omega_2)$ when the Lebesegue measure of $\Omega_2\setminus\Omega_2$ is not zero. Usually a minimality condition or a PDE for the extension brings back uniqueness.

Comment: @OskarLimka, thank you for your comment. Could you explain a little bit more that?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, in the cases I am interested in $H^m([-a,a])\hookrightarrow_c L^2([-b,b])\hookrightarrow H^{-m}(\mathbb{R})$ or $H^m([-a,a])\hookrightarrow_c L^2(\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow H^{-m}(\mathbb{R})$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a<b$. It looks to me that the Rellich-Kondrachov conclusion is valid in both cases i.e there are no problems, and that I can use the Aubin-Lions lemma then? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, they are compact.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune, thank you.